# kjournald and apache2 hang on xen vps

Tags: apache-2.2, server-crashes, kjournald

I have 2 low-traffic wordpress websites on a Debian 7 VPS (1G RAM, 1G SWAP, Dualcore 2.4GHz CPU). Between 5 and 10 days, `kjournald` hangs, the kernel reports and I/O error and the filesystem (ext3) goes to read-only and an inconsistent state. This obviously requires a reboot and manually running fsck. I've set `vm.dirty_ratio` to `5`, but other than that I'm at loss to what to do. The CPU load never goes over 3, the memory is stable (350 to 450MB used) and sufficient, the 1 GB swap isn't used and the only thing running on the server is `apache` `(mpm-worker)`, `php-fpm`, `mysql`, `fail2ban`, `proftpd` and a backup script that uses `tar/gzip` to store the webserver folders to another folder on the same partition of the hard disk. I'm at loss to what could cause such high I/O so that it hangs for more than 120s. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when the provider applied updates to Xen. The issue was caused by a conflict between the Xen host and the linux guest running 3.2.0 with an ext3/4 filesystem. Here's the bug report from Debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=688441